# Constraint formulation with binary variables if-then

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

I am working on an optimization problem which has the following constraint:

> Let $x_{j}, y_{j}$, $j=1, \ldots, J$ be a set of binary variables, it holds that, for $j', j'' \in J$ fixed, if
> $$\sum_{j' < j < j''}x_{j} = 0$$
> then either $y_{j'} = 0$ or $y_{j''} = 0$.

I know that the implication can be modelled introducing a binary variable $z_{j',j''}$ such that $y_{j} - z_{j',j''} \leq 0$ and $y_{j} + z_{j', j''} \leq 1$, but I do not know how to model the entire constraint formally with the introduction of big-M.

Any help will be appreaciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to enforce the following proposition:
$$\sum_{j' < j < j''}x_{j} = 0 \implies (y_{j'} = 0 \lor y_{j''} = 0).$$
Equivalently,
$$\left(\bigwedge_{j' < j < j''} \lnot x_{j}\right) \implies (\lnot y_{j'} \lor \lnot y_{j''}).$$
Now rewrite in conjunctive normal form:
$$\lnot\left(\bigwedge_{j' < j < j''} \lnot x_{j}\right) \lor (\lnot y_{j'} \lor \lnot y_{j''}) \\
\bigvee_{j' < j < j''} x_{j} \lor \lnot y_{j'} \lor \lnot y_{j''},
$$
which immediately yields linear constraints
$$
\sum_{j' < j < j''} x_{j} + (1-y_{j'}) +(1-y_{j''}) \ge 1.
$$